# Refined use of MFC FindFile API failing

Tags: c++, file, winapi, visual-c++, mfc

I use a custom .HMD format to binary encode some data in my VC++ MFC application. Imagine there are multiple HMD files in a folder, I would like to read all of their filenames.

I stumbled upon `CFindFile` class of MFC. I added a bunch of my HMD files to my project path and tried the following code -

```
CFileFind finder;
BOOL bWorking = finder.FindFile(_T("*.HMD"));
while (bWorking)
{
    bWorking = finder.FindNextFile();
    TRACE(_T("%s\n"), (LPCTSTR)finder.GetFileName());
}
```

This code worked! TRACE printed all the HMD files in the project path.

However, then I attempted doing the same from a random directory. I simply created a `data` directory in the project path and moved all my HMD files there, and tried the code again as follows.

```
CFileFind finder;
BOOL bWorking = finder.FindFile(_T("data\*.HMD")); // Only change is I added data to path
while (bWorking)
{
    bWorking = finder.FindNextFile();
    TRACE(_T("%s\n"), (LPCTSTR)finder.GetFileName());
}
```

However, this one failed to read filenames. `finder.FindNextFile()` returned `false`

Can someone please tell me how to fix my usage of CFindFile so I may be able to read files from any random directory?

P.S. I am using MultiByte Character Set.

Comment: Unrelated: Whenever possible, use full paths.  Get the application directory, then concatenate `"data\*.HMD`" to that.

Comment: `However, this one failed.`  Failed in what way?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It failed to read filenames. 'bWorking' was return `finder.FindNextFile()` returned `false`

Comment: @MooingDuck What advantage is there to using full paths?

Comment: @Golazo,  Since you're using Visual Studio, you didn't get any warnings that the string contained an unrecognized character sequence?  More specifically, `C4129`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie You're right. I did. Should have paid attention.

Comment: @Golazo: [Global Variables are Bad](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad) and CWD is (effectively) a global variable.

Comment: @Mooing in a console app, the working directory is part of the input to the program. So using it is fine. However, the mistake is often assuming that the working directory is the same as the directory containing the executable.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: If you're using it as an input yes, that's fine.  But I just refactored a ton of code that kept changing the CWD, so that I can now do it multithreaded.  Also, "File not Found" errors in logs are not fun when the real bug is that someone changed the CWD.

Comment: @MooingDuck How is the CWD set, can it be changed? I use app wizard to create projects and for me, it always sets the CWD as the folder where my source files are

Comment: @Golazo: When _debugging_ Visual Studio will use wherever the _project file_ resides.  When launched via double-clicking the exe, Windows will use different things, often "C:\WINDOWS\system32".  When launching from the command line, cmd.exe will use whatever _it's_ CWD is.  Your code can use SetCurrentDirectory (But I don't recommend it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape backslash characters. Instead of

```
"data\*.HMD"
```

use

```
"data\\*.HMD"
```

Comment: Ah! Worked!! Had forgotten about it.